# How does the Firebase iOS SDK perform its In App Purchase validation?

Tags: ios, firebase, in-app-purchase, firebase-analytics

In the Firebase iOS SDK a feature to validate Ina App Purchases was added ( Version 3.5.1). However, there is no additional documentation about the nature of the validation (server side, client side etc).

Does anyone know what sort of validation the SDK is doing?

Ideally in combination to this, I would love to get a callback from the SDK to tell me if an initiated purchase was valid. This would save developers from having to create their own server side validation if this is indeed how its being done.

Comment: it's totally insane that FBase don't yet offer server-side validation of app store transactions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The In App Purchase is done client side by some techniques to validate a transaction.
Currently, the validation is not 100% guarantee that's a transaction is valid so I'd recommend to have your own server side validation too as I have seen some games like Candy Crush easily got invalid transaction without server side validation while some games did have server side validation and they were much harder to generate invalid in app purchase. Keep in mind that some client side validation techniques can easily be changed or detected than server side validation ones as iOS programming is pretty dynamic.

Comment: Thanks, that is very helpful. Regardless, it would be useful to get a callback from the firebase SDK to know whether its client side validation was valid or not. Is there an appropriate channel where I can request this feature?

Comment: I'd recommend to create a feature request at https://firebase.google.com/support and they might consider whether this is a good idea to implement.